# add border to background

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup and style:

```
<input class="my-input" type="text />

.my-input {
    background: url(my-icon.png) no-repeat right center;
}
```

I actually created an input with an icon on the right.
Now I want to add left border to that icon. I am trying to do it without adding new elements.
Since :after and :before are not working with inputs, I can't manage to do it.

I don't want to use JavaScript and I don't want to add elements.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: So a border, to the *left* of the icon, that's on the *right*? A fiddle would help. Secondly, I would suppose the icon is displayed via an padding area on the input?

Comment: You can always assign another background, but it's not supported in older browsers. Waiting for jsfiddle to help.

Comment: Could you not draw a border on the icon itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple backgrounds feature. To render the vertical line, you can use `linear-gradient` trick. Here is the code details:

```
.my-input {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 2px, transparent 2px),
              url(http://placehold.it/30x30);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:right center;
  background-size:30px 30px;
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

## [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TLSAh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.my-input {
    background: url(my-icon.png) no-repeat right center;
    border-left: 3px solid yellow;
}
```